# function index parameter 3 is out of range

Tags: microsoft-excel

can anybody explain what is parameter 3 in the index function? and what is value 5?
I am attaching a picture here
[image: My_Excel_problam]

Answer (score 0):

`Name_list` (parameter 1) is a 2D array or range, `MATCH($A$2,birthday,0)` (parameter 2) represents row number (relative), and `MATCH($D$6,Living_area,0)` (parameter 3) represents column number (relative). Relative means that rows and columns count is for `Name_list` and not for the entire worksheet.